# How can I set a bitmap on button?

Tags: android, image, image-processing, bitmap

I have just a simple question. How can I set a bitmap on button? I use the method

```
.setBackgroundResource(int resid)
```

when I have drawable resource. But what can I do for bitmap?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use an `ImageButton`, and call `setImageBitmap()` to set the foreground image. `setBackgroundResource()` is for the button background, which needs to be a `StateListDrawable` to be effective.

Comment: @Joseph82: `Button` is for text captions. `ImageButton` is for images. You can use `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds()` with a `Button` to place an image along with a caption, though you would have to create `BitmapDrawable` objects for those.

Answer (score 1):

Call `setImageBitmap` on your button.

```
  myButton.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
```

Comment: I can find the method setImageBitmap. Are you sure is a method of Button class?

Comment: Its from ImageView. I am guessing.

Comment: You need to be using `imageButton` which is a subclass of `ImageView` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html